# SQL Trigger with cursor not working

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, cursor

I'm doing a sql work but I'm getting trouble with creating a trigger and I have no idea why.
Here's the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER artigo_funcionario
BEFORE INSERT ON encomendaartigo
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
artigo_invalido exception;
artigo number(3);
auxiliar number(1):=0;
auxiliar_numero number(3);

 CURSOR dotacao_funcionario is
  select a.artigo_id
  from artigo a, familia fa, dotacao d, encomenda e, funcionario f, categoria c
  where e.encomenda_id = NEW.encomenda_id
  and f.funcionario_id=e.funcionario_id
  and f.categoria_id=c.categoria_id
  and d.categoria_id=c.categoria_id
  and fa.familia_id=d.familia_id
  and a.familia_id=fa.familia_id;


BEGIN

  open dotacao_funcionario;
  loop
  fetch dotacao_funcionario into artigo;
  EXIT WHEN dotacao_funcionario%notfound;

  auxiliar_numero := NEW.artigo_id;
  if(artigo = auxiliar_numero) then
    auxiliar:=1;
  end if;

  end loop;
  close dotacao_funcionario;

  if(auxiliar=0) then
    raise artigo_invalido;
  end if;

 EXCEPTION
  WHEN artigo_invalido THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('O funcionário não pode encomendar o artigo introduzido');
END;
/
```

Be aware that the problem is not with the cursor so don't worry about the tables I'm using. the only one that is relevant is the "encomendaartigo" and it has the following attributes: "encomenda_id", "artigo_id".

The problem is that I'm can't quite use the "new.xxxxx" operator. if ran, the compiler log shows the following:

```
Error(8,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(10,30): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEW"."ENCOMENDA_ID": identificador inválido
Error(25,7): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(25,29): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.ARTIGO_ID' must be declared
```

I've tried everything and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the colon before the NEW. e.g.)

```
auxiliar_numero := :NEW.artigo_id;
```

Not

```
auxiliar_numero := NEW.artigo_id;
```

Optional implementation per your comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER artigo_funcionario
BEFORE INSERT ON encomendaartigo
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 l_check_artigo_id number := 0;

 CURSOR dotacao_funcionario is
  select 1
  from artigo a, familia fa, dotacao d, encomenda e, funcionario f, categoria c
  where e.encomenda_id = :NEW.encomenda_id
  and f.funcionario_id=e.funcionario_id
  and f.categoria_id=c.categoria_id
  and d.categoria_id=c.categoria_id
  and fa.familia_id=d.familia_id
  and a.familia_id=fa.familia_id
  and a.artigo_id = :NEW.artigo_id;


BEGIN

  open dotacao_funcionario;
  fetch dotacao_funcionario into l_check_artigo_id;
  IF l_check_artigo_id = 1 then
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'O funcionário não pode encomendar o artigo introduzido');
  END IF;

  CLOSE dotacao_funcionario;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF sqlcode = -20001 then
         dbms_output.put_line('O funcionário não pode encomendar o artigo introduzido');
       END IF;
        -- a simple RAISE will re-raise the exception
        RAISE;
END;
/
```

Comment: that's not the problem. I've tried that and whenever I put the colon before the NEW, a box to "enter binds" for that variable appears. That's not the problem then..

Comment: Trust me, the colon needs to be there. If you are getting prompted for binds then whatever tool you are using is doing you a disservice and assuming that it is executing a script that contains bind variables instead of trying to compile the trigger. If you can't figure out the correct setting to turn off variable replacement in your tool then add the colons, save it to a file, and compile it using the most basic option: Oracle's SQL*Plus.

Comment: ,so you're saying that I should use the colon both in the place you mentioned before and at line 13?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying

Comment: Don't know what that's from without seeing the actual script file as it might have an extra trailing byte on a blank line or something. But I assume that you now have a compile trigger as you wished?

Comment: No, I don't. When I do what you said, the "enter binds" box still appears. I don't know how to change the variable reaplacement setting nor I can work with Oracle's SQL*Plus. But at least I know that there's nothing wrong with the code itself...I think

Comment: What tool are you using? And I have strong reservations with the logic you have implemented. Why set auxiliar_numero := NEW.artigo_id if you are just going to use it to compare to the cursor return? why add a variable?. In fact why loop through a cursor at all to see if there is a record with a matching artigo_id when you could just have the cursor include that as a where clause and so only ever have to return one row if it exists? and if it exists you are just outputting a message - should you be refusing the insert? I have updated my answer with an optional implementation.

Comment: If you are using TOAD or SQL*Developer, have the trigger code be the only thing on your worksheet and run it with F5 to "execute as script" and see if that will compile it properly. If using something else, let me know.

Comment: I'm using Oracle Sql developer. And yes, you're absolutely correct with everything you said about the logic implemented by me. My first script looked a bit like yours but I changed it to narrow the error I was getting, like adding auxiliary variables. And yes, I want to refuse the insert with an exception, how can I do that?

Comment: You want to raise an exception, and you did that - but then you trapped it in the exception handler and did the dbms_output. If you still want it to be an exception after you trap and handle it then you need to re-raise it at that point. I have updated my example to raise a custom exception with your message.

Comment: So should I do what I did but call the raise exception again inside the exception handler? I'm sorry if this is not what you meant, I'm still new to the exception handling thing. Maybe showing me would be ideal, if not too much for you already, giving that you already gave a huge help

Comment: yes, if you trap an exception to do something with it, but want it still be an exception, you need to re-raise. Give me a sec to edit....

Comment: That looks just about right, but I'm getting an "encountered the symbol "=" when expecting..." error.

Comment: In the exception handler probably? yeah - just noticed something in there too. Hard to ensure code compiles for you when I can't test it here first..

Comment: Yes, of course, I took care of it, but thanks anyways!! Okay, so, the script compiles well and the cursor is working great (I tested the select aside from the rest) but the trigger is not, well, it's not triggering when supposed to.

Comment: And it's solved. For the record, if you want to know what wasn't working, the problem lied when it fetched if the cursor existed. When it did, it would raise an exception, but it was the other way around. A simple swap of the '1' with a '0' did the job. With no further questions to add, I want to thank you for your effort, it surely paid of big time!